Is the ETS function from forecast appropriate for skewed environmental time series data? does the time-series data need to meet certain criterion?
I have environmental data that is usually just analysed with the nonparametric man-kendall and sens slope, because it is skewed.  Can the ETS function which picks what exponential smoothing model to fit, work on this sort of data? or does the data need to have certain qualities/ undergo preprocessing?

If you have a time series (which I assume since you are thinking of ETS), then whether your data is skewed overall is not very informative - an "overall" skew may simply be seasonality, which ETS will happily pick up. Can you tell us more about your situation? What data do you have, on what temporal granularity? What is the objective of your analysis?
